# How do I set preferences for a plugin running in IBM Notes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes

I have written a plugin for IBM Notes - a sitebar plugin.

Using policies I am can get my plugin out to the end user, but have do a push the preferences?

In the extension.xml there is a node called preferences as a child to webcontextConfiguration - can and how do I use it?

Link :
[Best practices for developing plug-ins for an IBM Lotus Notes standard client](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Best_practices_for_developing_plug-ins_for_a_IBM_Lotus_Notes_standard_client)

Link : [Deploying Plugins and Widgets for Lotus Notes and Sametime](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Deploying_Plugins_and_Widgets_for_Lotus_Notes_and_Sametime)

Answer (score 1):

To push out preferences for plugins you use the Desktop Policy. Once you have that open you select "Custom Settings" tab then "Managed Settings" tab under that.

Click "Edit List..." the dialog will let you specify plugin name, key and value to push down.

The following link give further details.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_USING_POLICIES_TO_ASSIGN_MANAGED_SETTINGS_TO_NOTES_CLIENT_USERS_STEPS.html